# Opening Websql database in Wkwebview Cordova ios 14

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova

We are trying to update our cordova app to a new sql plugin and remove the deprecated websql database. The android version works without a problem, but the ios version blocks every attempt to open the old websql DB. We always get the message "Websql is deprecated". The main problem is, to remove websql, I need to migrate the data from the database to a new sql lite DB, but this is only possible if I´m able to get the data from the old DB. No matter what I do, I need to conect at least one last time to websql.

Has someone faced a problem like this under ios and found a solution? We are using cordova 10 and ios cordova 6.1.1, but I also tried older versions.

The only way it works, is using a simulator with an older Ios version, but this doesnt helpt our customers, since they cant just downgrade their system. Also, our App is in the App store and is still using websql, which is running without a problem there. Why can the App on the Store use websql, but I can't to migrate our data?

We tried running the app in Preflight and also tried old builds, but the problem stays always the same.

Comment: We face same problem. Any solution? 
We have verified that in ios 14.2, if the app was already published it still works Websql but it does not work if you compile it now with Xcode 12.2

Comment: I couldn´t find anything so far. Nothing I tried worked and it seems like the data could be lost without a chance to retrieve it.

Comment: Did you guys find any solutions to this? Is is possible to force the build version back to 13.0? It doesn't seem to work if a change the version directly from the project settings, maybe there is an alternative?